# How to configure Intellij log level to debug for Maven output

Tags: maven, intellij-idea, slf4j

I have created a simple maven application in intellij and using slf4j for logging.

I am not able to see debug logs in console

I see from C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2019.3\plugins\maven\lib\maven3\conf\logging\simplelogger.properties

The default log level is set to INFO

> org.slf4j.simpleLogger.defaultLogLevel=info

How do I configure this in Intellij to debug or for that matter warn?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

To configure Maven output level there is Settings (Preferences on macOS) | Build, Execution, Deployment | Build Tools | Maven | **Output level** option:

[image]